# Group Records by Property to be put in a table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have a list of objects like so:

```
ID    |    First Name    |    Location    |    Division    |    Age    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          John              Building1         ISS              22
 2          Alex              Building1         ISS              30
 3          Chris             Building1         HR               41
 4          Mary              Building1         HR               25
 5          Monica            Building1         HR               46
 6          Ian               Building2         Accounting       37
 7          John              Building2         Accounting       32
 8          Justin            Building2         Sales            22
 9          Trevor            Building2         Sales            26
10          Shelley           Building2         Sales            34
11          Troy              Building1         Network          25
```

**THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE OF WHAT I HAVE... I HAVE A LOT MORE**

My goal is to create a table each time if the location differs **OR** the division differs.

So I want my outcome to be:

**Table 1**

```
Building 1 - ISS // table header
------------------------------------------------------------------
// table body
 John              Building1         ISS              22
 Alex              Building1         ISS              30
```

**Table 2**

```
Building 1 - HR// table header
------------------------------------------------------------------
// table body
 Chris              Building1         HR              41
 Mary               Building1         HR              25
 Monica             Building1         HR              46
```

**Table 3**

```
Building 2 - Accounting // table header
------------------------------------------------------------------
// table body
 Ian              Building2         Accounting              37
 John             Building2         Accounting              32
```

**Table 4**

```
Building 2 - Sales // table header
------------------------------------------------------------------
// table body
 Justin              Building2         Sales              22
 Trevor              Building2         Sales              26
 Shelley             Building2         Sales              34
```

At the top of my view I have:

```
@model List<ProjectName.Models.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel>
```

I would like to use only 1 foreach loop, because like i stated above there are a lot more locations and division and I would prefer not to have to create a foreach loop for every different location and division.

How can this be done?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have added an extra in the table above.  That person is a part of Building1 location, but since there is only one of him, instead of having 1 whole table generated for just one person I would like to add him to the group Building1 ISS.

Is there some kind of conditional statement that I can do to do this?

**UPDATE 2**

```
ID    |    First Name    |    Location    |    Division    |    Age    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1           John             Building1     Administration      40
 2           Melissa          Building1     Division1           32
 3           Sean             Building1     Division1           26
 4           Timothy          Building1     Division1           33
 5           Joe              Headquarters  Administration      33
 5           Jason            Headquarters  Staff               33
 5           Greg             Headquarters  Staff               33
 5           Brett            Headquarters  Staff               33
 1           Rob              Building2     Administration      40
 2           Nate             Building2     Division2           32
 3           Leslie           Building2     Division2           26
 4           Phil             Building2     Division2           33
```

**Goal**

I do not care about the Headquarters people.. if there is only 1 person in a division then so be it.. I only care about building1 and building2 people.

So I would like Rob added to Building2 Division2 group and John added to Building1 Division1 group.

Can a conditional statement be used here to check for count and a where statement to check for location name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query the records using a `.GroupBy` on both the `Location` and `Division` as keys.

Start with view models representing your view

```
public class MainVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }
}
public class ChildVM
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And to generate your model

```
var data = ... // your query to get the database records

IEnumerable<MainVM> model = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Location, x.Division }).Select(y => new MainVM()
{
    Title = y.Key.Location + " - " + y.Key.Division,
    Children = y.Select(z => new ChildVM()
    {
        FirstName = z.FirstName,
        Location = z.Location,
        Division = z.Division,
        Age = z.Age
    })
});
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<MainVM>
....
@foreach(var table in Model)
{
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th colspan="4">@table.Title</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var row in table.Children)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@row.FirstName</td>
                    .... // do you really need to repeat Location and Division which are already in the header?
                    <td>@row.Age</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

---

Based on your updated question, you would need to select all `ChildVM` records where the `.Count()` of `MainVM.Children == 1`, and concatenate then to the first `MainVM`

```
IEnumerable<MainVM> model = data.GroupBy(... // as above
model.First().Children = model.First().Children
    .Concat(q.Where(x => x.Children.Count() == 1).SelectMany(x => x.Children));
```

and then return only those `MainVM` who have `.Children.Count > 1`

```
model = model.Where(x => x.Children.Count() > 1);
return View(model);
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect.  However, I have updated my question.  Can you assist with that?

Comment: Are you referring to the row with `ID = 11, FirstName = "Troy" ..`?

Comment: Correct, that is the row I added

Comment: Well you can just check all records where `Children.Count == 1`, and then move those to the first record, and then exclude records where `.Count() == 0`. Not sure you could do that all in one linq query though - let me have a think about it for a while.

Comment: Okay sounds good. Thank you for your help.  I thought of checking the count, but like you, I couldn't think of a way to do all of that in the same query.

Comment: I think you will need a separate query for this. Bit busy at the moment so might be an hour before I can update.

Comment: That's fine. Take your time.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your new requirement, but I'm guessing there may be other combinations to consider, for example what is there is one person in `Building 2/AnotherDivision` - would you really want that person to be added to the `Building 1/ISS` group?

Comment: I am trying what you provided, but I am getting a red squiggly under `q.Where` in the `Concat`.  Saying cannot resolve symbol 'q'.

Comment: Did you mean `model.Where`?

Comment: Yes you are correct, there are other combinations.  Let me update the question to be suitable for my needs.

Comment: Please check under **Update 2**

Comment: Nevermind I have found the solution.  Thank you for your help!